# Testing the data sent by Flask's send_file()

Tags: python, flask, openpyxl

I have a [Flask](https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) view that generates an Excel file (using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) from some data and it's returned to the user using `send_file()`. A *very* simplified version:

```py
import io
from flask import send_file
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

@app.route("/download/<int:id>")
def file_download(id):

    wb = Workbook()
    # Add sheets and data to the workbook here.

    file = io.BytesIO()
    wb.save(file)
    file.seek(0)

    return send_file(file, attachment_filename=f"{id}.xlsx", as_attachment=True)
```

This works fine -- the file downloads and is a valid Excel file. But I'm not sure how to test the file download. So far I have something like this (using [pytest](https://pytest.org/en/latest/)):

```py
def test_file_download(test_client):
    response = test_client.get("/download/123")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.content_type == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

Which passes, but I'd like to test that the (a) the filename used is as expected and (b) that the file... exists? Is an Excel file?

I can access `response.get_data()`, which is a `bytes` object, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check that the filename used is as expected you could check that the `Content-Disposition` header is as expected. For example:

```
assert response.headers['Content-Disposition'] == 'attachment; filename=123.xlsx'
```

To check "the existance of the file" you could for example check that for some test data it lies within an expected range of size. For example:

```
assert 3000 <= response.content_length <= 5000
assert 3000 <= len(response.data) <= 5000
```

Another level of verifying that the Excel file works would be attempting to load the data back into `openpyxl` and checking if it reports any problems. For example:

```
from io import BytesIO
from openpyxl import load_workbook
load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(response.data))
```

Here you risk running into some sort of exception like:

```
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Which would indicate that the data contents of the file are invalid as a Excel file.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! Very useful techniques. That's the second time I've learned from you in the past week - thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Thanks! But how do you read the response from the server? When it serves a file?